# How to output the checkbox value in the email template only if it is checked?

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer

I am working on a project where user can send the selected checkbox to the client by providing email address. The html code is:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
    <form method="POST" action="/kidclinic/register">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="with-gap" value="http://test1.com" name="kidclinicchecbox1" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
            <label class="form-check-label">Text 1</label>
        </div> 
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="with-gap" value="http://test2.com" name="kidclinicchecbox1" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
            <label class="form-check-label" >Text 2</label>
        </div> 
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="with-gap" value="http://test3.com" name="kidclinicchecbox1" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
            <label class="form-check-label">Text 3</label>
        </div>        
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Send to</label>
            <input value="{{email}}" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" >
        </div>
        <p style="margin-top:16px"></p>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I have given the same name for every input checkbox type inorder to grab the value once it is checked. The output of this is:
[html output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3XOa.png)

I am using nodemailer for sending mail. My code for nodemoailer is.

```
const output = `
        <p>Fill up the forms</p>
        <h3>Please click the links</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>${req.body.kidclinicchecbox1}<br></li>
        </ul>                
    ` 

    async function main(){
        // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
       let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
         host: "hostname",
         port: 25,
         secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
         auth: {
           user: 'user.name', 
           pass: 'user.pass' // generated ethereal password
         },
         tls: {
           rejectUnauthorized: false
         }
       });
        // setup email data with unicode symbols
       let mailOptions = {
         from: '"Form App" ', // sender address
         to: req.body.email, // list of receivers
         subject: "Node contact Form app", // Subject line
         text: "Hello world?", // plain text body
         html: output // html body
       };
        // send mail with defined transport object
       let info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)
        console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);        
     }
```

All is working fine but i could not edit the email output meaning i am not being able to add anchor tag in output nor i can give break line. The email output looks like this [email output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weMNM.jpg). Is there any possible way to add anchor tag in output of the email? Please let me know if i have missed anything?

Answer (score 0):

You have not added  tag inside

. Check this code

```
const output = `
        <p>Fill up the forms</p>
        <h3>Please click the links</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="${req.body.kidclinicchecbox1}"> ${req.body.kidclinicchecbox1}</a><br></li>
        </ul>                
    `
```

Comment: Thank you so much it is working however it is displaying in the same line. may i ask how to break line between the links as they appear on the same line?

Comment: split it by comma(,) and then use loop.